# Display new subtotal when Quantity is changed on the Magento product page

Tags: magento

I want to replace the standard Magento quantity input text field with a quantity dropdown.

Does anyone know how to update the js so that the new subtotal is displayed upon changing the quantity value?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you talking about the product or cart page?